# python error while i read data from file

Tags: python, python-2.7, read-data

If i input data like

```
username = "exampleusername"
password = "examplepassword"
email = "example@example.com"
year = "2018"
```

software work good but i need software read data from file
and  if  do this

```
file = open("data.txt", "r")
username = file.readline()
password = file.readline()
email = file.readline()
year = file.readline()
```

i see this statement from website where i put this information 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl13U.png)

This problem i see if i read data from file. I not see this problem if i give data in code. But i need to software read this data from file  :)

sorry for my english i stil learn him.

Comment: You need to show us the contents of your file and what the variables are once you have read them from the file. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is how you stored the data in you `data.txt` file:

```
exampleusername
examplepassword
example@example.com
2018
```

Then the problem is probably because `.readline()` returns a `\n` at the end of each line. To avoid that, you can use `.strip()` for example to remove that extra character like so:

```
file = open("data.txt", "r")
username = file.readline().strip()
password = file.readline().strip()
email = file.readline().strip()
year = file.readline().strip()
```

If your `data.txt` only has these four lines, you could do it in a shorter way like this:

```
username, password, email, year = open("data.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
```